# Save DataGridView changes by closing form

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm writing a program in which i can add items to a `DataGridView`. This works perfectly. And I got a Delete button, to remove the items from `DataGridView`. This is working, but not perfectly. It delets my items but if I restart the program, the items are still here. I'm saving the items to an xml file. So here you can see my code for adding items to `DataGridView`:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml"))
            {
                using (File.Create(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml")) { }
            }

            xmlnode = new XElement("iToDo",
                    new XElement("Name", txtName.Text),
                    new XElement("Priorität", comPrio.Text),
                    new XElement("Anfangsdatum", txtStart.Text),
                    new XElement("Enddatum", txtEnd.Text),
                    new XElement("Bemerkung", txtComment.Text)
            );

            try
            {
                xmlFile = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
                xmlFile.Add(xmlnode);
            }
            catch (XmlException)
            {
                xmlFile = new XElement("ToDos", xmlnode);
            }

            xmlFile.Save(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
            DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
            flatDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Save\save.xml");
            DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
            dataGridToDo.DataSource = table;
        }
```

And here you can see my code for deleting rows:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridToDo.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataGridToDo.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
            }
        }
```

And I tried to put this in `Form_Closing()`, which not works:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Can someone give me a hint how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehm.. I'm a bit puzzled by your FormClosing code. You write the xml file from xmlFile and immediately read it again? On the form closing the result of reading it in would superfluous as the data grid will be destroyed quit

Comment: Oh, I forgot to delete this out of `Form_Closing()`. This was only a test. I will edit the post. Do you have an idea how I can fix the problem?